# Why are V and I out of phase for a resistor in parallel with an inductor for the resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

V<sub>th</sub> is the voltage across R<sub>L</sub> so the current through the load should be in phase with V<sub>th</sub>. But the current through the load is 1.8A with phase angle of 100.43 degrees and the voltage across it is 72.76V with phase angle of 134 degrees. I am not able to figure out why they are different.

[image]

Comment: If you draw the Thevenin's ckt, you will understand that Vth is not the voltage across RL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *\$V_{th}\$ is the voltage across \$R_L\$*

No it isn't.

\$V_{TH}\$ is the open circuit voltage seen at the terminals of \$R_L\$ when \$R_L\$ is disconnected. It will be lower when \$R_L\$ is connected. It's called the Thevenin voltage of the source and it isn't the loaded value; it's the unloaded value.

In other words, the solver of the problem turned the 150 volt source, the 40 Ω resistor and the inductor and capacitor into a new source (\$V_{TH}\$) in series with \$Z_{TH}\$. This was done to the exclusion of \$R_L\$ because this is what you do when you transform a more complex source into a simpler source.

That new source becomes this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3cLz4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And clearly, it has an open circuit voltage of \$V_{TH}\$ but will be loaded down when \$R_L\$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage across the load is not Vth as you state in your question.  This voltage is not calculated in the solution. Vth is in series with Zth and RL. Therefore the voItage across the load is the result of the voltage division between Zth and RL combined with Vth. If you calculate that, you will find it is in phase with the current through RL.

Answer (score 0):

The current across Rl is in phase with the voltage across Rl.

But the current across the voltage source branch (which then splits between the inductor and Rl) is not in phase with the current\voltage across Rl.

As the current across the voltage source branch is not the same as the current across Rl, it may not be in out of phase with Rl's voltage, unlike the current that actually flows across Rl which has to be in phase with the resulting voltage across Rl (given that the voltage across a resistor is not phase shifted from the current across the same resistor).